# How to read multiple integers from single line java

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, integer

I want to read multiple integers from 1 line of input, i know there are more questions on this topic but none are applicable in my situation, so please don't delete this question. 
i want a code that allows multiple integers to be input on a single line, and be stored separately in an int array. The input can be 1-13 integers. so it could be 2 3 4, or it could be 7 or it could be 2 2 5 8.
I tried this:

```
while(scanner.hasNextInt()){
    ida[k] = scanner.nextInt();
    k++;
    }
```

but it never stops asking for integers, my code just stops here and you have to keep putting more integers in.

Comment: Please show at least some attempt to solve this yourself beyond "I Googled it". This question is essentially "give me codez, because I couldn't find them on the internet" - as such it is off topic here.

Comment: you dont have to be so negative, i actually did a lot more ill add it to the post

Comment: `nextInt` takes a single `int`. If you want multiple `int`s, you might need to just read the line and parse it manually.

Comment: I do not see what is wrong with your code. Perhaps you have errors in your code prior to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A small example which splits after a blank, so a example input could be:

---> 3 4 9 10

```
String input = scanner.nextLine();
String integers[] = input.split(" ");
if(integers.length > 13 || integers.length < 1){
    //ErrorHandling
}
for(String number : integers){
    try {
        int num = Integer.parseInt(number);
        //Add to array
    } catch(NumberFormatException e){
        //number String input was not a number
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot :)
but it says " readLine is undefined for the type Scanner

Comment: if the answer solved your problem, pls mark it as correct

Comment: and also NumberFormatexception cannot be resolved to a type, do i need to import anything? i already have java.utli.*

Comment: you need to import: java.lang.NumberFormatException

Comment: I did that but it still gives the same error, I'm using eclipse luna, maybe it has to do with that?

Comment: Maybe you wrote the e from exception in lowercase instead of uppercase?

Comment: i did xD, but i still have the readLine problem, do i also need an import for that?

Comment: but normally you can look for all the methods, when you press ctrl + space if your cursor is on the variable name

Comment: Thanks, that is one error less. and i didn't know that.
but this line: String input = scanner.readLine();
keept telling me that this method readline() is undefined for the scanner type.

Comment: yeah no problem :), if i solved your problem pls mark it as correct

Answer (score 0):

If i get your question, you can try from this code:

```
             public static void main(String[] args){
                 int[] a = in.readInts(args[0]);    //in cannot be resolved
                 StdOut.println(count(a));          //StdOut cannot be resolved
            }
```

Comment: Oupss! i'm sorry i just looked out and seems that was posted 4years ago